# Use my laptop as Webserver using IIs7.x?

Tags: iis-7, dns, webserver

I'd like to set up IIS7 to use a purchased domain.

- I have a domain, call it www.mydomain.com. Bought a while ago...
- My domain name is supplied by GoDaddy.com
- I have Windows 8.1 with IIS7.x installed.
- I've created my website and added the site to IIS: Sites/MySite
- I have setup the bindings as follows:

  - **IP address:** All Unnasigned
  - **Port:** 80
  - **Host name:** www.mydomain.com

I think this is correct, but am not sure.

When I visit Godaddy and go to my domain settings, I have created a Host Name record with the hostname 'MySite' and the IP address that I got from when I typed 'What's my IP' in Google.

Also in Godaddy, I have gone to the 'DNS Zone File' tab and under 'A (Host)' I've added the same IP from Google.

PS. I've also forwarded port 80 on my SuperHub 2
[image]

Does anyone know how to do this and if I am doing it correctly?

Do I also need to set up my 'Hosts' file?

Comment: `by GoDaddy.com I have Windows 8.1 with IIS7.x installed` is godaddy hosting the server? `the IP address that I got from when I typed 'What's my IP' in Google` if you are hosting the site on your laptop you'll need to set some port forwarding in your modem.

Comment: I want to host my site, Godaddy just provide the domain name.

Comment: can be tricke for a couple of reasons: 1) you use a laptop: if you shut it down your website is down. If you are at another network, it's not reachable. 2) your ISP probably doesn't supply a static IP: this means it can change over time and the IP you saw in Google will change

Comment: 3) you'll need to forward port 80 in your modems/routers to your laptop to reach your site from the outside world. 4) dns request can take up to 24 hours to update all tables globally.

Comment: Yeah, I don't mind it shutting down when I turn off the laptop, I just want it for testing reasons. I use Virgin Media in the UK - the IP is not static as far as I know, but it very seldom changes (can be years). I just want it to test, so am not too bothered about setting up again.

Comment: in that case: forward port 80 in your network to the internal LAN ip of your laptop.

Comment: I've forwarded port 80 on my router (see updated question)

Comment: Would I still be able to browse the web if I forwarded port 80 to internal LAN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Stefan has said above, you'll want to do a few things:

1. Find your router/cable modem's IP address. It's likely the same as what Google shows you for "Whats my ip".
2. Use GoDaddy's DNS manager and create an A record and put that IP address in there. It could take a few hours for DNS to propagate.
3. Connect to your router's web UI and setup forwarding for port 80/443 to your laptop's internal address.

There are a few potential problems though-

1. ISPs like to change the IP address on people unless you pay for
   their business service. To get around this, you might consider a
   dynamic DNS solution like http://www.noip.com/
2. ISPs also commonly
   block inbound service ports on home services (another reason to
   consider the business service). Commonly blocked are
   80/443/25/21/22.
3. You might consider issuing your laptop's MAC
   address a static IP instead of using DHCP, so that the forwarding
   always works (and another device on your home network doesn't grab it).

Hope this helps!